# Item not deleting from array using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following a tutorial trying to learn Redux. I got the first action working, which is a simple GET API call, but am stuck on the next action I'm trying to create. The code looks like the following:

In the Component:

```
class ShoppingList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  handleClick = id => {
    console.log("component " + id);
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;

    return (
      <Container>
        <ListGroup>
          <TransitionGroup className="shoppingList">
            {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
              <CSSTransition key={id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <Button
                    className="button1"
                    color="danger"
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={e => this.handleClick(id, e)}
                  >
                    &times;
                  </Button>
                  {name}
                </ListGroupItem>
              </CSSTransition>
            ))}
          </TransitionGroup>
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ShoppingList.propTypes = {
  getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);
```

In my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: 3, name: "Eggs" },
    { id: 4, name: "Milk" },
    { id: 5, name: "Steak" },
    { id: 6, name: "Water" }
  ]
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case DELETE_ITEM:
      console.log("reducer");
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In my actions file:

```
export const getItems = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_ITEMS
  };
};

export const deleteItem = id => {
  console.log("actions");
  return {
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: id
  };
};
```

However, when I click on the button to try to delete an item from the list, nothing happens. I can see in the Redux console that the action is being dispatched, however it seems to have no effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in `deleteItem` action `{ type, payload }`. Instead you can have `{ type, id }` or using `payload` in the reducer return statement.

I would do the following - so you are passing the `id` with the `action` instead of `payload`:

```
export const deleteItem = id => {
  console.log("actions");
  return {
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    id
  };
};
```

Or the best option for later purposes - keep `payload` just adding `id` as property:

```
// action
export const deleteItem = id => {
  console.log("actions");
  return {
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: { id }
  };
};

// reducer
case DELETE_ITEM:
   // here destructuring the property from payload
   const { id } = action.payload;
   return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
   };
```

I hope this helps!